# Select From Multiple tables with group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have two views:
Purchase_Details view:

```
InvoiceId
ItemId
Quantity
Price
ExpireDate
ItemCode
StoreId
```

and Sale_Details view

```
InvoiceId
ItemId
Quantity
Price
ItemCode
StoreId
```

and Item Table:

```
ID
Name
SalePrice
PurchasePrice
```

Purchase_Detail View data

```
Id  StoreId ItemCode        Price            Quantity         ItemId       ExpireDate
51    1      345            300.00           1.00                5          2019-10-25
52    1      348            300.00           22.00               5          2019-10-04
53    2      348            300.00           17.00               5          2019-11-11
54    1      345            300.00           8.00                5          2019-12-12
```

Sale_Details View data

```
Id  StoreId    ItemCode          Price         Quantity         ItemId
55       1       345            300.00          4.00              5
56       1       348            300.00          3.00              5
```

I want to found sum of quantity of each item grouped by ItemId and ItemCode.

Second: is it better to put the sales and purchase and the same table or separate them (as I did?

Comment: you sample is not clear ... is not present  the column itemID ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to union the data together first, and then group by so your sum crosses the sets.  You can do this with a CTE.  Something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Detail AS (
    SELECT ItemId, ItemCode, Quantity FROM Purchase_Details
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ItemId, ItemCode, Quantity FROM Sale_Details 
)

SELECT ItemId, ItemCode, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM CTE_Detail
GROUP BY ItemId, ItemCode
```

As far as your question about "what is better", that depends on how you want to use it.  Obviously, there is a little additional complexity in this query by having them separate, but it might help you in other areas.  I believe you said they are views, so can't you have it both ways?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
with purchases as (
    select
        ItemId,
        ItemCode,
        sum(quantity) as purchase_sum
    from
        Purchase_Detail
    group by
        1,
        2
),
sales as (
    select
        ItemId,
        ItemCode,
        sum(quantity) as sales_sum
    from
        Sales_Details
    group by
        1,
        2
)
select
    ItemId,
    ItemCode,
    (
        purchase_sum - sales_sum
    ) as net
from
    purchases
join sales
        using (
        ItemId,
        ItemCode
    )
```